# build 32 and 64 bit builds in Installshield

Tags: installshield, installscript

I need to build a setup.exe for a 64 bit machine in Installshield installscript project. 
I am trying to do this in Installshield 2013

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you are building an MSI file you can't do this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2008/01/15/different-packages-are-required-for-different-processor-architectures.aspx